# Why is my new pine fence turning black? Can I stain right over it without creating a bigger future headache?

Tags: wood, fence, mold, stain, pressure-treated

We put in a new pine fence about 2-3 months ago.

(*Southern Yellow Pine, from Lowes. They called it “Severe Weather Pressure Treated Pine”*)

I have been trying to stain/seal it for the past month and a half but we have had one of the wettest summers on record. And when it’s not raining, it’s 100 degrees and 30000% humidity.

Over the past 2 weeks the panels have rapidly started turning grey/black. I don’t think the sun ever directly hits this side of the fence so I assumed it is mold..?

1. Based on the picture and info, is my assumption correct?
2. If so, do I now have to remediate the mold by doing the whole bleach scrub and dry process?
3. If I don’t do the bleach scrub and just stain right over it, will I be creating a recipe for disaster or just end up with a sub-par looking stain job?

[image]

Comment: You used the pressure-treated tag, why ? What kind of wood are the posts?   Curious as to why Pine and not  a more weather  resistant wood, cedar, redwood etc.?

Comment: They’re Southern Yellow Pine. It was all we could afford unfortunately. They were only $50 per section from Lowes. They called it “Severe Weather Pressure Treated Pine”

Comment: Thanks,  “Severe Weather Pressure Treated Pine” - All of the wood or just the posts?  I added the pertinent info to your  question, You can use the edit button to add or modify as necessary.

Comment: pine doesn't stain well and neither does PT, it generally looks splotchy and amateurish even under the best conditions. You don't want to seal the fence either, that's more to resist standing water like on a deck, but used vertical, it can slow the natural wetting and drying out of the wood, causing splitting, rotting, and un-even gaps.

Answer (score 3):

That is natural aging , the most rot resistant wood redwood turns gray within 5 years , cedar within 3 and that’s in Oregon.
If you stain it a color or paint it it will hide the aging but this is normal with most any wool product, pressure treating keeps it from rotting not aging.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. Initially I assumed it was simply aging as it was kind of my indicator that it had officially ‘dried out’. I started getting worried because in the last 3 days the color went from 1-3 discolored panels to 20+ panels And we had just received after receiving 4” of rain and tropical humidity so we were drenched for days and I started to fear mold. Glad that is not the case. 
Looks like I’ll start staining/sealing tomorrow FINALLY . Thanks again!

Comment: I remember having this happen to my first deck years and years ago. All the sealers that guaranteed to keep the deck looking new never stopped the gray.+1